# How to bend and flatten a mesh

Tags: modeling, sculpting, 3d-printing

I have a model to be 3d printed. It is a figure sitting on a bench. As you can see in the image, the cloth is touching the bench. I want to bend the cloth and flatten the surface so that the figure can be correctly positioned on the bench.

[image: Screenshot showing the touchline]

[image: Screenshot showing the desired bend direction]

I want to avoid sculpting the model. Is there other alternative?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Another way of doing this is using the surface deform modifier. This still requires some sculpting/modelling, but should be easier that sculpting the original mesh.

First, create a grid mesh that roughly conforms to the complex mesh.

[image]
[image]

Then, with the complex mesh selected, add a surface deform modifier and set your grid mesh as the Target. Then click Bind.

[image]

With proportional editing, you can edit the grid mesh and the complex mesh will follow.

[image]